# Is it possible to copy and paste iCal events in iPad / iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ical, copy-paste

Is there any way to copy an event in iCal in iPad or iPhone and paste it to a different day? At times, I want to keep the original calendar entry, but repeat on a different day? I am not looking to use the repeat function, as that forces one to use more predictable repeat.

Comment: Yeah - I wish too. I usually satisfy myself with just copying the main event text & pasting into subsequent days. If I'm home, alt/drag on the Mac is a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Aside of using the duplicate and repeat there is no copy/paste function.

You can submit a request for the function at http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe Apple's team wish users use the Repeat->Custom function when adding an event to create multiple entries of the same thing.
Yet, I also agree a copy/paste feature is highly lacking there...

Answer (score 1):

A work-around:  email the event to yourself (or create a new event in a new email to yourself).  Hover the cursor over the event in that email, click the down-arrow that appears, edit the date, and then "Add to Calendar."  You can do this for as many dates as you like.

Comment: Can't email an event on the iPhone (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0):

I have "CalenGoo" on my iPad -- and there's a drag and copy feature which I find indispensable!!  It syncs with Google Calendar (which was why I got in the first place years ago) -- I think they have an iPhone version too, although I like how it works better on my iPad.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this as well when trying to input my work schedule (I work in shifts). The solution I found is to manipulate the repeat function in the following manner: Add the event, select custom repeat "every month", select the applicable days of the month, and finally set the custom repeat to end on the last day of that particular month. It's a hack, but it works. One does wonder why there is no copy/paste feature though...

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, but I'm using next workaround for non recurring events
(it looks complicated, but try it out, it works quite fine):

1. Set the event to be repeated e.g. *Every Day*
2. Go to the repeated event on the day you need it and set the *Repeat* back to *None* and hit the *Done* button.
3. Then change the time or add a note, if needed.
4. When closing the event, a pop-up message appears telling *This is a repeating event* and prompting you eighter to *Save For Future Events* or to *Cancel*.
   Choose *Save For Future Events*.

**Result**: you have the event *copied*.

5. Now, go back to the original event and turn the *Repeat* function back to *None*.

**Result**: The original event is not recurring any more.

Note: You can use the same trick to *Copy* recurrent events as well. But then, in step 5, you need to go to the next to last of your wanted recurring events and delete it.
Choose *Delete All Future Events*.

Comment: This is the most ideal workaround given the limitations of iOS. I’d upvote this, but the original request was for a copy/paste solution that doesn’t use the Repeat function. But thankful you offered a usable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can not copy/paste an event but you can repeat an event for N-days in a row by using repeat/custom/1 day till end-date for the repeat.